# How to enable a checkbox in Gridview only when it's in the Edit mode?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

This is how I have my checkbox column currently:

```
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hide/Show" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Hide_Show">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="HideShowChk" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Hide_Show") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have no code in my code behind because it's not necessary. Basically, a user can check or uncheck it, but it won't be reflected in the database unless I actually go into Edit mode, check or uncheck it, and then hit update so that the changes ARE reflected in the database.

Is there a way to have it so that the checkbox is "disabled" or anything of that sort while it's not in edit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use edititemtemplate for enabling it in the edit mode

```
 <edititemtemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="HideShowChk" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Hide_Show") %>' />
 </edititemtemplate>
```

If you still want to use the check box inside the ItemTemplate make it disable using CSS or jQuery.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. However, the column now shows nothing. Thoughts?

Comment: put it in the <ItemTemplate>  also and make it disabled something like  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false" />

Comment: With this stunt on the asp:CheckBox, the <ItemTemplate> is all you need:
Enabled='<%# GridViewName.EditIndex.Equals(Container.DataItemIndex) %>'